# Meaning of wouldn't have to

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

The situation is that when a child got up in the morning he found his school bag all ready for school. Then he narrated this:

> Amazing! I wouldn't have to run about the house collecting books.

I cannot understand if  "wouldn't" used as the past form of will not here.

Comment: "If you do x for me, **I wouldn't have to do y"**.

Comment: Presumably he is narrating in the past tense. At the time, he might have said to himself "I won't have to...", but in telling the story later "[I realised that] I wouldn't have to..."

Comment: Past tense here: Amazing. I realized I wouldn't have had to do x.

Comment: I find the use of 'narrate' a bit odd.